# Search XmlDocument with multiple values as input

Tags: xml

I have to search an XML Document given below from `.net`

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <cricketers>
        <cricketer type="lefty">
            <name>Shikhar Dhawan</name>
            <role>Batsman</role>
            <position>Point</position>
        </cricketer>

        <cricketer type="righty">
            <name>Virat Kohli</name>
            <role>Batsman</role>
            <position>cover</position>
        </cricketer>

        <cricketer type="righty">
            <name>Shami</name>
            <role>Bowler</role>
            <position>SquareLeg</position>
        </cricketer>

        <cricketer type="lefty">
            <name>Zaheer Khan</name>
            <role>Bowler</role>
            <position>FineLeg</position>
        </cricketer>
    </cricketers>
```

I would like to select all the `cricketer` nodes, where the name contains **'an'** or **'mi'**

Here is the xpath statement I tried:

```
XmlNodeList BasicNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("cricketer[name='%an' and name='%mi%']");
```

Comment: `Can you help me on this?` We might, but show us first what you tried. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: XmlNodeList BasicNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("cricketer[name='%an' and name='%mi%']");

Comment: You'd better add this in the question, not in comments (click the "edit" button). And give a little context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your XML is invalid. The first line should be this (notice lowercase `xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Then, your XPath has to look like this to get what you want:

```
xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//cricketer[contains(name,'an') or contains(name,'mi')]");
```